# Meaning of [\p{Lu}] in ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, ada

How should one interpret the rule

```
fragment LETTER_UPPERCASE  : [\p{Lu}] ;
```

at

https://github.com/okellogg/ada_antlr_grammar/blob/master/antlr4/ada.g4#L200

Is `\p` an ANTLR-specific escape sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\p{Lu}` or `\p{Uppercase_Letter}` is a unicode category. It matches an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant. By wrapping `[` and `]` around it, it is made into a [character set](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-elements).

See:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html
- https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/1688